# When using List or Map, Flutter keeps passing a reference, but I need a copy

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, mongodb-query, immutability

I'm using this package `mongo_dart` to make requests to my DB. 
I want to compose my query based on some RangeSlider values, so my final query will be an AND of these queries. Here is my sample code.

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as mongo;

class RangeSlidersTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RangeSlidersTeststate createState() => _RangeSlidersTeststate();
}

class _RangeSlidersTeststate extends State<RangeSlidersTest> {
  RangeValues range1Values = RangeValues(0, 0);
  RangeValues range2Values = RangeValues(0, 0);
  mongo.SelectorBuilder finalQuery;
  Map<String, mongo.SelectorBuilder> queries;

  @override
  void initState() {
    queries = Map<String, mongo.SelectorBuilder>();

    super.initState();
  }

  void composeFinalQuery() {
    finalQuery = mongo.SelectorBuilder();

    List<mongo.SelectorBuilder> queriesList = queries.values.map((v) {
      return v;
    }).toList();

    if (queriesList.length > 0) {
      finalQuery = queriesList.removeAt(0);
    }

    queriesList.forEach((query) {
      finalQuery = finalQuery.and(query);
    });

    print("Final query: ${finalQuery.map}");
  }

  void onRange1Change(RangeValues r) {
    setState(() {
      range1Values = r;
      queries.remove("range1");
      queries["range1"] = mongo.where.inRange(
          "wins1",
          r.start,
          r.end);
      composeFinalQuery();
    });
  }

  void onRange2Change(RangeValues r) {
    setState(() {
      range2Values = r;
      queries.remove("range2");
      queries["range2"] = mongo.where.inRange(
          "wins2",
          r.start,
          r.end);
      composeFinalQuery();
    });
  }

  Widget _buildUIRangeSliders() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[  
            RangeSlider(
              max: 14,
              min: 0,
              divisions: 14,
              onChanged: onRange1Change,
              values: range1Values,
            )
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            RangeSlider(
              max: 14,
              min: 0,
              divisions: 14,
              onChanged: onRange2Change,
              values: range2Values,
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[_buildUIRangeSliders()],
    );
  }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the variable queries (of type Map) it keeps getting bigger and bigger every time I change both values. And I suspect that this happens because, somehow, when I'm doing `finalQuery = queriesList.removeAt(0)` I'm getting a reference to the first element (although I'm using a `map` function to prevent this).

So I think that the proper way to solve this is to make a copy of `mongo.SelectorBuilder` which, unfortunately is a package from a external library.

Is there any easy way to achieve this mechanics?

Thanks!

EDIT. I have also tried (with no luck):

```
  void composeFinalQuery() {    

    finalQuery = queries.values.map((f)=>f).toList().reduce((q1, q2) {
      return q1.and(q2);
    });

    print("Final query: ${finalQuery.map}");
  }
```